# Costs for downloading a file from S3 to EC2 using Presigned URL within same region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an EC2 instance that needs to download a file from S3 via a presigned download url. Both instance and S3 bucket are in the same region (and account) and the EC2 instance is also accessing the internet via NAT Gateway. Am I correct in my assumption, that the traffic from S3 to EC2 does not count as "within the same region" and it actually goes through the internet?

And are the S3 outbound traffic costs (0,09$/GB) in addition to the general outbound costs of 0,15$/GB? Any other traffic-related costs I am missing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If the connection goes through the NAT gateway, you will be charged for the bandwidth on that. If you enable the S3 endpoint in your VPC, connections to S3 from withing your private VPC will not go through that NAT gateway and not incur the additional bandwidth charges. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the answer! When using the S3 vpc endpoint, do I have to connect to S3 via API/SDK or can I still use the presigned url that points to the public S3 interface and it will automatically route the request through the vpc endpoint?

Comment: The endpoint should work for all requests to S3, including presigned urls, however I have not personally tested that

Answer (score 1):

One of the exceptions to S3 bandwidth charges is to an EC2 instance in the same region.  The signed URL is just an authentication mechanism that doesn’t change the request source.

From: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

> Data transferred out to an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)
> instance, when the instance is in the same AWS Region as the S3 bucket
> (including to a different account in the same AWS region).